# Unable to unlock Android bootloader

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock

I have a Weimei We, it's an Spanish-Chinese brand, yes, really odd, anyway the other day I touched something in the system partition trying to remove the root (I rooted the phone a few months ago) and the phone wouldn't turn on again, so I started thinking how it could be fixed and it occurred to me that maybe flashing fastboot would be helpful, so I tried to flash the partition with an image that I downloaded from the internet(not really trustworthy but it was my only hope) but I was unable to write on the partition, I thought that maybe the bootloader was locked, that will explain it, I tried to unlock the bootloader using the fastboot commands

> fastboot oem unlock

and

> fastboot flashing unlock

a disclaimer appeared saying that it would void my warranty, etc... and when I pressed okay..... this

> Bootloader cannot be unlocked(or something like that)

I've emailed the manufacturer but they said they cannot provide me with the info to unlock the bootloader because they do not recommend doing that and telling me would be incoherent (asshole move)

I don't really know how the locking of the bootloader works, I guess the manufacturer has a private key zand cannot share it, but all the phones I had in the past, let me unlock it, I guess this happens to me for buying a "non commercial brand"

So my question here is, is there any way I can unlock it?

Thanks in advance

[Weimei We Homepage](http://www.weimeimobile.com/en)

Comment: Not every phone accepts that command (in fact very few). For a phone of this low popularity you're likely out of luck. Since you can contact the manufacturer, why not just ask them how to restore it?

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have found the solution to my issue, there is an option in the developer options called *OEM unlocking* which allows you to unlock your bootloader in fastboot, I haven't tried this in my phone since it's being restored, but I'm pretty sure that my terminal has that option

I will give it a try as soon as I have my phone

Comment: Congrats on finding the culprit. Let's see how things go with flashing that "untrustworthy" image you mentioned. Mind at least leaving a link to it for people to see?